# Translate 'suffered for your sanity' in precise chinese

Tags: translation

In the song 'Vincent', it sings:

Now I understand
What you tried to say to me
And how you **suffered for your sanity**
And how you tried to set them free

Conversely, 'suffer from your sanity' can translated as '难得糊涂',

How to translate it directly and elegantly?

Comment: search web e.g. with ＂中文：suffered for your sanity＂，get many hits, e.g. 你清醒的時候承受了多大的痛苦

Comment: 你如何承受世人皆醉我独醒的折磨

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'suffered for' = '因~而受苦'

'your' = '你的'

'sanity' = '理性'

*insanity = 疯狂 (n). The opposite of '疯狂' is '理性' (rationality) or '清醒头脑'(sound mind)*

> "suffered for your sanity"

"**因你的理性而受苦**" or "**因你的清醒头脑而受苦**"

> Yumi Tada wrote: *make sense.but not like a song lyrics*

You can give up some accuracy for style and wrote:

" And how you suffered for your sanity" -- "**你何以因清醒而受罪**"

Comment: make sense.but not like a song lyrics.

Answer (score 0):

starry starry night
夜晚充的星

Now I understand
现在我知道
What you tried to say to me
你要说的
And how you suffered for your sanity
你多过了苦难仍然正常
And how you tried to set them free
你要解放他们
But they would not listen,
他们没听你的话
They're not listening still
还没听着你
Perhaps they never will
也许他们永远不会明

Or a more complicated version:

starry starry night
满天星星的夜空
Now I understand
现在我懂得
What you tried to say to me
你那时想要对我说什么
And how you suffered for your sanity
你是如何在遭受磨难之后还保持你的理智
And how you tried to set them free
你是如何努力地解放他们
But they would not listen,
可惜他们不听你的话
They're not listening still
他们现在依然不听
Perhaps they never will
也许他们永远不会懂